# Duplicate row adding to my Emp table And Empty row also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to Angular applications.

When user enter details in text boxes and clicks on add button then in Emplist table that row added again click on that add button same row added how to fixed it give me a suggestion and one more is user not entered any details of Employee in that textbox then clicks on add button then its adding empty row.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.emplist = [
                   {empname:'samudrala',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 450'},
                   {empname:'soujanya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 451'},
                   {empname:'suguna',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 452'},
                   {empname:'sangeetha',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 453'},
                   {empname:'sadhanandham',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 454'},
                   {empname:'jai',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 455'},
                   {empname:'vijay',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 456'},
                   {empname:'Ajay',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 457'},
                   {empname:'Sandya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 458'},
                   {empname:'Raamu',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 459'}
                   ];
    $scope.addItem = function(){
    if($scope.empname!=' '&& $scope.empsalary!=' '&& $scope.empid!=' '){
      $scope.emplist.push({'empname':$scope.empname,'empsalary':$scope.empsalary,'empid':$scope.empid});     
    }     
    }
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
.txt-center{
 text-align:center;
 }
html,body{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color:#333;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  
}
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1>List Of Employee</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <table style="width:100%;">
 <thead>
 <tr height="35">
 <th width="5%">S.No.</th>
 <th width="30%">EMP Name</th>
 <th width="33%">EMP ID</th>
 <th width="32%">EMP Salary</th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat ="x in emplist" height="25">
 <td class="txt-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
 <td class="txt-center">{{x.empname}}</td>
 <td class="txt-center">{{x.empsalary}}</td>
 <td class="txt-center">{{x.empid}}</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>
 <h1>Add Employee</h1>
 <table style="width:100%">
 <thead>
 <tr height="35">
 <th width="5%">S.No.</th>
 <th width="30%">EMP Name</th>
 <th width="33%">EMP ID</th>
 <th width="32%">EMP Salary</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr height="25">
 <td><button ng-click="addItem()" style="width:100%;">Add</button></td>
 <td><input type="text" style="width:99%;" ng-model="empname"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" style="width:99%;" ng-model="empsalary"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" style="width:99%;" ng-model="empid"/></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset all your fields after insert

Try the following:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.emplist = [{
    empname: 'samudrala',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 450'
  }, {
    empname: 'soujanya',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 451'
  }, {
    empname: 'suguna',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 452'
  }, {
    empname: 'sangeetha',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 453'
  }, {
    empname: 'sadhanandham',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 454'
  }, {
    empname: 'jai',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 455'
  }, {
    empname: 'vijay',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 456'
  }, {
    empname: 'Ajay',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 457'
  }, {
    empname: 'Sandya',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 458'
  }, {
    empname: 'Raamu',
    empsalary: '4.5 - pam',
    empid: 'Emp - 459'
  }];
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    if (typeof($scope.empname) == "string" && typeof($scope.empsalary) == "string" && typeof($scope.empid) == "string") {
      $scope.emplist.push({
        'empname': $scope.empname,
        'empsalary': $scope.empsalary,
        'empid': $scope.empid
      });
      $scope.empname = $scope.empsalary = $scope.empid = null; //reset fields    
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1>List Of Employee</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr height="35">
        <th width="5%">S.No.</th>
        <th width="30%">EMP Name</th>
        <th width="33%">EMP ID</th>
        <th width="32%">EMP Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in emplist" height="25">
        <td class="txt-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td class="txt-center">{{x.empname}}</td>
        <td class="txt-center">{{x.empsalary}}</td>
        <td class="txt-center">{{x.empid}}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <h1>Add Employee</h1>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr height="35">
        <th width="5%">S.No.</th>
        <th width="30%">EMP Name</th>
        <th width="33%">EMP ID</th>
        <th width="32%">EMP Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr height="25">
      <td>
        <button ng-click="addItem()" style="width:100%;">Add</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" style="width:99%;" ng-model="empname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" style="width:99%;" ng-model="empsalary" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" style="width:99%;" ng-model="empid" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks But Empty row Still Adding

Comment: test if the fields are empty before appending

Comment: how i am new for this please example

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do:

- Clear the emp object after adding
- Use ng-form to validate for empty objects

Answer (score 0):

At first you clear all the fields then you inputted value it will add in your array.

use like this:

```
   $scope.empname="";
   $scope.empsalary="";
   $scope.empid="";
   $scope.emplist = [
                  {empname:'samudrala',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 450'},
                  {empname:'soujanya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 451'},
                  {empname:'suguna',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 452'},
                  {empname:'sangeetha',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 453'},
                  {empname:'sadhanandham',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 454'},
                  {empname:'jai',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 455'},
                  {empname:'vijay',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 456'},
                  {empname:'Ajay',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 457'},
                  {empname:'Sandya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 458'},
                  {empname:'Raamu',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 459'}
                  ];
      $scope.addItem = function(){

            if($scope.empname!='' && $scope.empsalary!=''&& $scope.empid!=''){
                console.log('add'); $scope.emplist.push({'empname':$scope.empname,'empsalary':$scope.empsalary,'empid':$scope.empid


                                                        });
```